# Shortcut multiple Mysql SUMS over intertwined date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When a user on my site logs in, multiple queries are performed for stats.

```
SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM stats WHERE date BETWEEN $start_month AND $end_month
SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM stats WHERE date BETWEEN $start_last_month AND $end_last_month
SELECT SUM(earnings) FROM stats WHERE date BETWEEN $start_year AND NOW()
//etc...
```

I feel that I am "cheating" the Mysql engine by asking it to `SUM` all of these on separate queries. For example, when it calculates the years earnings it is also calculating the monthly earnings within that...but then I query it again anyways.

Is there a better way to get SUMS for multiple date ranges that are intertwined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can use `CASE` to calculate the `earning`.

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN $start_month AND $end_month THEN earnings ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN $start_last_month AND $end_last_month THEN earnings ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN $start_year AND NOW() THEN earnings ELSE 0 END)
FROM    stats
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why this works better than separate queries? Thanks :)

Comment: It's fewer round-trips between PHP and MySQL; each of those round-trips has a cost to it.

Comment: Is this SQL standard or mySQL specific?

Comment: If you are calling this from an application, it only queries the database once, as connection to the database requires resources a lot.

Comment: @fredrik most RDBMS supports this.

Comment: @JW I'm surprised, such useful thinks are usually exclusive to one or the other :D To think that they "all" support it, amazing.